# Bug in ad spacing on DIY.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Over at [DIY.se](http://diy.stackexchange.com), I noticed that the sidebar ads are being cut off on the right by the edge of the sidebar:

[image: truncated ad]

Using Chrome's inspector, it turns out the problem is in `.everyonelovesstackoverflow` in `all.css`:

```
.everyonelovesstackoverflow {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:0 8px 8px 8px;
}
```

Setting the padding line to `0 8px 8px 0` fixes the problem:

[image: non-truncated ad]

Comment: I'm looking into this now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment